# Windows periodically disconnects/resets local area network when there is no internet access

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, lan

This issue is first discovered when a few workstations in a small network would periodically lose access to a server in the same local network whenever there is no internet access. The network is based on a single router acting as DHCP, and the issue does not happen if the network is connected to the internet.

All computers in the network are connected via ethernet, and the computers that exhibit this issue don't have a wireless NIC so this can't be a wifi issue either.

This issue only happens to a few specific computers in the network. For now one common factor shared by the computers showing this issue is that they are running Windows 7 (No Windows 10 computers in the network have had this issue, yet.)

When the issue happens, the networking icon in the notification tray at the bottom right would show a spinning circle, then after a few seconds it would return to the normal icon with a yellow triangle for the lack of internet access. Running a logged ping session confirms this, as the problematic workstation would receive replies from the server but every once in a while there would be a few `Destination host unreachable`.

For me this it seems like Windows is periodically resetting something (network stack?) to try to *fix* or detect an internet connection, and in the process of which causing a brief disconnection to the LAN.

Trying to find troubleshooting solutions for this on the internet is especially difficult, as most solutions seem to be for re-establishing connections to the **internet**, instead of issues within the LAN when there is no internet.
So far, I've tried the following to no avail:

- restart router
- disable power management of the wired NIC in device manager
- use a fixed IP for the workstation instead of relying on DHCP from the router
- run `net config server /autodisconnect:-1` on the workstation
- disable NLA (Network Location Awareness) service on workstation
- disable IPv6 on the workstation

Comment: There is no harm in disabling Power Management. I always use DHCP for workstations, never Static IP. I have not found a need to disable NLA. IPv6 should not be disabled because doing so may cause problems. Did you upgrade the Firmware on the Router?  I would do that and then a hardware reset on the router. Set it up again and test.

Comment: @John I just remembered that restarting the router was actually the first thing I tried, but I can try a hard reset of the router too. But how can the router be the cause when only a few computers in the network have issues, while others are fine?

Comment: There can be an incompatibility between the router firmware and the computer network card. That is why I suggest this.